# Linux server (not in Azure) joins Azure AD

Tags: linux, azure

I know we can use realmd to join a local Active Directory server.

But how to join Azure AD, can realmd join Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to join the on-premise Linux devices to use Azure AD ,

- you can enable Azure AD domain Services on your tenant , and setup a azure site to site VPN with the same azure VNET which is hosting the Azure AD domain Services managed domain and then use the following articles to join the Linux OS .
- The following article is written taking into consideration Ubuntu OS however , I believe you should be able to use same instructions on other Linux versions as well with maybe some additions/slight modifications of commands as per the package availability on different distributions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-join-ubuntu-linux-vm#

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/226171/want-to-enable-sso-for-ubuntu-machine-with-azure-a.html

However, if the Linux machines are deployed in Azure, you can also check the below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad

Answer (score -1):

This is a situation where you would join the Linux machine to your local AD and use Cloud Sync or Azure Active Directory Connect to tie it in with Azure.